# Where did Delete Profile move to?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

It appears [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/649528) is no longer accurate. There is no longer a *Delete Profile* link under *Site Settings*.

It looks like it changed in the last week or so.

How does one delete unwanted site memberships now?

---

Below is a screen capture of the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange. I'm showing membership in the community, with reputation points. I also received a notification today of a badge for being an active member for a year.

[image]

Comment: Is that a script blocker extension in your toolbar?

Comment: The 'S' in the toolbar is HTTPS Everywhere.

Comment: This is [still accurate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/282094), see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E20Th.png - only if you are suspended or on the child meta will it be hidden; so it's a dupe either way, unless you can improve your question.

Comment: @Rob this looks like an honest mistake others might make. *I* didn't notice it was meta at first. Heck, I didn't even know this was a rule. I don't think this is a bad question.

Comment: @Rob - Feel free to delete the question. I can't do it.

Comment: It's not a case of deleting, it's a case of finding the best duplicate and marking it a duplicate of that. You should be able to instantly close your question as a duplicate of the first link in your question.

Answer (score 10):

You're on the site's meta. You cannot delete your profile from meta sites, only from the main site (which deletes the meta profile also). You can head back to your main site profile by clicking on the "Main user" link at the top right of the profile page.

Comment: I got there by clicking on the "Congratulations, you earned the Yearly badge". Why is the Yearling message taking me to a Meta site?

Comment: @jww you get yearling badges on both meta *and* main.

Comment: @jww because there are two yearling badges, one for the main site and one for the Meta site